# What do the different forms of scope.$apply do in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

**Method 1**

```
scope.tasks.pop(task);
scope.$apply();
```

**Method 2**

```
scope.$apply(scope.tasks.pop(task));
```

**Method 3**

```
scope.$apply(function()
{
   scope.tasks.pop(task);
});
```

My results seem to be the same in each case. I understand that when modifying scope outside of "normal" angular, you must call `$apply` for the change to be picked up in data bindings. But I don't understand the various forms of $apply and why you might call it with no arguments vs doing your scope modifications in a function passed to $apply.

What's the difference and when should you use which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better understand differences please consider the following pseudo-code for $apply function from the angular documentation [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

When you calling it with function or expression string as an argument, angular can handle errors thrown from that function properly and forward them to $exceptionHandler service. In any case it will call $digest() to update bindings at the end.

Comment: Oh OK. So it doesn't have any effect on what gets digested, just if any errors get reported thru $exceptionHandler. I guess that makes sense. Thanks.